# Start-up error on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 problem, I recently changed a lot of things in regedit and other stuff to personalize my own PC, but at every boot I have an error:

> The module `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Ahnworks\Advsplsh64.dll` failed to load.
>   Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.
>   The specified module could not be found

I tried to find the file but `ahnworks` folder does not exist.  I also wanted to create it and add the dll but I couldn't find the file.

Answer (score -1):

This is a run dll error. This is caused by the specified file having a registry key to start up, but the file isn't there. It could be caused by a virus that was removed or a registry edit. If you feel comfortable editing the registry, you could delete a key similar to the file name, or there might be an entry in the Windows Task Scheduler that you can delete without the risk of editing or deleting something important in the registry. That's how I got rid of one of my RunDll errors.

**I will go more in-depth with the one I recommend the most: The Task Scheduler:**

1. Open the control panel.
2. Search for Task Scheduler, it will be under administrative tools.
3. Open it and open the "task scheduler library" item on the list to the left.
4. Search for the item that best resembles the error and delete it.

Of course, there are probably websites that can give you a better tutorial, but these are the basics.

Comment: could you tell me more like, how to do this, please?

Comment: @ChristianMichelSolbreux I've edited to be more in-depth.

Comment: @Ramhound That wasn't implied, I thought he meant when he gets into the desktop.

Comment: You are right!!

Comment: Can't find the error in there, searched on other websites but still can't find something to resolve my problem